# Node.js IF statement not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs, node-modules

Okay, I'm almost going crazy here. I am trying to create a Todo list that renders page title and content (array) dynamically using EJS. I've created a `list.ejs` page with the embedded JS codes appropriately i.e. `<%= listTitle %>` and `<%= newListItems[i] %>`. I'm trying to use the if statement to redirect appropriately when a post request is made. I'm tapping into the `req.body.list` of the post request to determine its value. Then

```
if (req.body.list === "Work List") {
    workItems.push(newItem);
    res.redirect("/work");
  }
  else {
    listItems.push(newItem);
    res.redirect("/");
  }
```

Here's more code to work with:

This is where I created the arrays:

```
let listItems = [];
let workItems = [];

// Generates Date String in long format
let day = date.getDate();
```

**This handles the GET request for the home (/) route.**

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
 // Passes Page title for home page and the home list array
  res.render("list", {
    listTitle: day,
    newListItems: listItems
  })
});
```

**And this handles the GET request for the /work route.**

```
app.get("/work", function(req, res) {

  // Passes Page title for work page and the work list array
  res.render("list", {
    listTitle: "Work List",
    newListItems: workItems
  })
});
```

What essentially happens is that, when I make a post request from the /work page, instead of the "if statement" to trigger and the `list.ejs` page rendered with *Work List* as the title and *workItems* array loaded in the content, it just redirects me back to the "/" route, pushes the newItem into the *listItems* and renders the date as the page title and the *listItems* array as the content. It's as if the "if statement" is ignored completely. I don't know what's going on.

**EDIT**

Here's the full POST code;

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {

  let newItem = req.body.newItem;

// IF statement to determine page/contents to be rendered
  if (req.body.list === "Work List") {
    workItems.push(newItem);
    res.redirect("/work");
    console.log("if now working");
  }
  else {
    listItems.push(newItem);
    res.redirect("/");
    console.log(req.body);
  }

});
```

Comment: What is the value of `req.body.list`? And make sure you get the entire thing - say, it might  be `"Work List "` with extra whitespace.

Comment: Also, when you are sending `listTitle: "Work List",` but checking for `list`. Is there anything that makes an extra mapping from `list` to `listTitle`?

Comment: show more of the code which handles the POST, you mention post, but all your code is for GET.. also show how your posting it up..

Comment: hi @LawrenceCherone I've added the code that handles the POST.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah there's no white spacing. The value of ```req.body.list``` is ```"Work List"``` as a string. This value comes from the initial value of the ```listTitle``` sent with the GET request for the ```/work``` route. But when I try to use this value in the if statement for the POST route, it just doesn't work.